# Scala chaining functions with andThen type mismatch

Tags: scala

I have a bunch of functions that clean text and splits them into words. Minimal example:

```
val txt = "Mary had a @little \nlamb"
val stopwords = Seq("a")
def clean(text: String): String = text.replaceAll("\n*\r*", "")
def tokenize(text: String): Seq[String] = text.split("\\s")

val cleaned = clean(txt)
val tokens = tokenize(cleaned)
```

This code works as expected. However not really idiomatic.
I had hoped to do this:

```
clean(txt) andThen tokenize
```

But the compiler complains about this with the error `type mismatch; required: Char => ?` at the tokenize function.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`clean` returns a `String`. You're trying to use `andThen` on a `String` instance (since you're invoking the *method* with `clean(txt)`) and the compiler infers it as a `PartialFunction[Char, ?]` (because `WrappedString` inherits `AbstractSeq[Char]` which inherits `PartialFunction[Char, A]`). That is why you're seeing the type mismatch. If you want to compose the two together, turn them into function types using eta-expansion:

```
val res = clean _ andThen tokenize
println(res(txt))
```

Function composition works on Scala functions, not *methods* (there is a distinction), and that is why we have to first expand the method to a function (`clean _`), and then the compiler will be able to infer `tokenize` for us without the need to manually expand it.

Comment: Interesting, I get it. Didn't know about the eta expansion. I have some reading to do :).